# Why aren't external variables added to .dynsym table?

Tags: global-variables, elf

From my understanding of .dynsym, it should contain the symbols that should be visible from an external program. I tried a simple program that contain this line:

```c
extern int global = 1000;
```

I thought the executable would contain the `global` symbol in its .dynsym, but it is not the case. Is my understanding of this section wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought the executable would contain the global symbol in its `.dynsym`

Why did you think that?

By default, only symbols referenced by some other shared library participating in the link are exported in the dynamic symbol table from the executable.

You can force *all* symbols to be exported in the dynamic symbol table using `--export-dynamic` linker flag:

```
$ cat foo.c
int global = 1000;
int main() { return 0; }

$ gcc foo.c && nm -D a.out | grep global
# no output

$ gcc foo.c -Wl,--export-dynamic && nm -D a.out | grep global
0000000000004028 D global
```

Comment: That's more clear now. Also, I always find the @GLIBC symbols when I compile and link my executable. Are they there because the libc needs to reference the binary's GOT to fill it with the addresses?

Comment: @Aramya They are there because of copy relocations: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter4-84604/index.html